# What can I do with the questions which may not get answers in near future?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I have a question here- [How can I make use of `::selection` for <input> in chrome browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782793/how-can-i-make-use-of-selection-for-input-in-chrome-browsers). It is about a css selector to specify color to the content with in  elements. That works in Firefox and doesn't work in Chrome. The Mozilla developer docs say that the selector is no longer a standard one.

So I may not get answer to it. Can I close it or wait until I get a solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's entirely up to you.

Stack Exchange doesn't impose a time limit for questions to get answered; some questions don't get a good answer for a year or two after they are asked (but this is rare).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your post, you *did* receive some useful comments. In this case, you have a partial-answer scenario.

So I'd let it alone - think that you're at least honoring the effort of the commentator

Generally, Robert is right - yeah, it is up to you. who knows though , maybe someone out there in Uzbekistan knows it.